# I need to multiply every other number by 3 but dont know what i'm doing wrong

Tags: python, math, numbers

```
print("Welcome")
barcode1 = input("Please enter your first digit")
barcode2 = input("Please enter your second digit")
barcode3 = input("Please enter your third digit")
barcode4 = input("Please enter your fourth digit")
barcode5 = input("Please enter your fifth digit")
barcode6 = input("Please enter your sixth digit")
barcode7 = input("Please enter your seventh digit")
barcode1 = barcode1*3
print(barcode1)
```

Instead of the number being multiplied by 3, the solution comes out as 111

Comment: Please add some more details to your question. What are you struggling with?

Comment: Can you please read the edit and format your question?

Comment: What was your input for barcode1?

Comment: the input was 1, i read somewhere that it comes out as 111 because it is a string and not an integer but i do not know how to change it

Comment: @LPK sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: What do you mean by multiplying every other number by 3? You're only multiplying the first number, you're not doing anything with the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like that:

```
codes = []
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        codes.append(int(input("Please input your Barcode {}: ".format(i))) * 3)
        if i == 6: break
        i += 1
    except ValueError:
        print("Something went wrong!")

print(codes)
```

Add a try-catch statement around it and try to cast your input to int. With that you could also input a string but your script wouldn't crash.

Answer (score 1):

The confusing phenomenon here is that python supports string multiplication as well as integer multiplication! To the inexperienced this may seem confusing, but it's actually a very nice feature. The following can be done:

```
>>> string = 'hi!'
>>> multiplied_string = string * 4
>>> multiplied_string
"hi!hi!hi!hi!"
```

So as you can see, multiplying a string repeats its contents `n` times, where `n` is the number it is multiplied by.

In your case you're expecting to multiply a numeric value, but the `input` function is returning a string value instead of a numeric value. That means that when you multiply it, instead of performing numeric multiplication, python does string multiplication.

Simply transform the result of `input` into an integer by using the `int` method. Or, you can even write a function to accept numeric input from the user.

```
def input_int(msg):
    '''
    Repeatedly asks the user for a valid integer input until a validly
    formatted input is provided.
    '''
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(msg))
        except:
            print('Please enter a numeric input.')

print("Welcome")
barcode1 = input_int("Please enter your first digit")
barcode2 = input_int("Please enter your second digit")
"........"
print(barcode1 * 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

change `barcode1` from a string to an integer, for example:

```
b1 = int(barcode1)*3
print(b1)
```

Comment: it worked it nows comes out with 3 instead of 111, thanks